# Outer rails for a Dell PowerEdge 1950

Tags: dell, rackmount

I'm looking at buying a Dell PowerEdge 1950 on eBay. It comes with rails (HN185 and GU092) but as best I can tell these are only the inner rails. Does anyone know which outer rails these go to? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Racksolutions](http://www.racksolutions.com/dell-rapid-rail-slide-rail-kits.html) has a good selection of Rails for Dell systems. Some of these rails are better then the ones that come from Dell.

Call Dell Sales and see if they can provide you with a list of all Dell 1950 and 2950 rail parts. You might need to be nice or act interested in buying some products. The list does exist, but I left it at my last jobs.

Comment: +1 for racksolutions.  great products.

Comment: Once we got the server, we got the service tag and found what came with it originally.

Comment: @Andrew: Congrats. Did you get any help from Dell Sales or Support, or did you manage to track this down on your own?

Comment: We got it on our own. We took the kit number that was sent with the order, and found a matching set of rails from Dell's website. We ended up ordering the entire rail kit, since we couldn't find only the outer.